# Is there a way to repeat a message with exception handling until input is correct?

Tags: java, loops, exception, while-loop

I am doing a project and have made a read method to read in user's input, however, I want to return a print statement if they do not enter the correct type of value and keep repeating this until they enter correctly. This is the code so far, but it doesn't seem to print my print statement.

```
package Project;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;

public class Read
{
  // Will return user input with exception handling.
   public static String read(String label)
   {
      boolean success = false;
      System.out.println( "\nProvide your " + label + ":" );
      System.out.print( "> " );

      BufferedReader input = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));

      String value = null;

      while (!success) {
         try {
            value = input.readLine();
            success = true;
         } catch (IOException ex) {
            System.out.println("Sorry that was an invalid input. Try again.");
            ex.printStackTrace();
         }
      }

      return value;
   }//Read Method.
}//Class.
```

Comment: What constitutes a valid or invalid input?

Comment: I want an invalid input to be null and spaces

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to loop as long as  `value` is invalid, so for you `value == null || value.isEmpty()`. So put the prompt (`>`) in the loop too.

I would take the error handling out of the loop because this is not something you can recover from. It would not be related to the use input, but more of a system failure, ie the program can't read the input stream. So just say an error occurred and end.

```
public static String read(String label) {
    String value = "";

    BufferedReader input = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
    System.out.println( "\nProvide your " + label + ":" );

    try {

        while (value == null || value.isEmpty()) {
            System.out.print( "> " );
            value = input.readLine();

            if(value.isEmpty()) {
                System.out.println("Sorry that was an invalid input. Try again.");
            }
        }

    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println("An error occurred.");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return value;
}//Read Method.
```

Comment: You have saved my life!! Thank you :)

Comment: You had most of it, just a matter of ordering then correctly